# Computing the variance of a matrix

Tags: matrices, statistics

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables and we let

$x=\begin{bmatrix}X+2\\3X\\3Y-1\end{bmatrix}$

How do you define a variance-like characteristic of a random vector variable?

Unfortunately, I'm not sure where to start. Let's say that I have $E(X)$, $E(Y)$, $var(X)$ and $var(Y)$. How should I proceed?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analogous entity is the covariance matrix. In the case of $x$ the covariance matrix is

$$\Sigma_x=\begin{bmatrix}
c_{11}&c_{12}&c_{13}\\
c_{12}&c_{22}&c_{23}\\
c_{13}&c_{23}&c_{33}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

where
$$c_{11}=Var(X+2)=E[(X+2-E[X+2])^2]=E[(X-E[X])^2]=Var(X).$$
$$c_{12}=E[(X+2-E[X+2])(3X-E[3X])]=3E[(X-E[X])^2]=3Var(X).$$
$$c_{13}=E[(X+2-E[X+2])(3Y-1-E[3Y-1])]=E[(X-E[X])(3Y-3E[Y])]=E[3XY-3XE[Y]-E[X]3Y+3E[X]E[Y]]=0.$$
$$c_{22}=Var[3X]=9Var(X).$$
$$c_{23}=E[(3X-3E[X])(3Y-1-E[3Y-1])]=0.$$
$$c_{33}=9Var(Y).$$

So,

$$\Sigma_x=\begin{bmatrix}
Var(X)&3Var(X)&0\\
3Var(X)&9Var(X)&0\\
0&0&9Var(Y)\\
\end{bmatrix}.$$